# how to access Dataproc cluster metadata?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

After the creation of a cluster, I'm trying to retrieve the URL address of my additional components (without using the GCP Dashboard). I am using de [Dataproc python API](https://googleapis.dev/python/dataproc/latest/gapic/v1/api.html) and more specifically the `get_cluster()` function.

A lot of data is returned by the function but I cannot manage to find the Jupyter gateway URL or other metadata.

```
from google.cloud import dataproc_v1

project_id, cluster_name = '', ''
region = 'europe-west4'

client = dataproc_v1.ClusterControllerClient(
                       client_options={
                            'api_endpoint': '{}-dataproc.googleapis.com:443'.format(region)
                        }
                    )


response = client.get_cluster(project_id, region, cluster_name)
print(response)
```

Does anyone as a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have followed [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/jupyter-notebook) to setup Jupyter access by enabling Component Gateway, then you can access the Web Interfaces as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/dataproc-gateways#viewing_and_accessing_component_gateway_urls). The trick is that this is included in the API response for the [`v1beta2`](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/ClusterConfig#EndpointConfig) version.

Changes needed in the code are minimal (no additional requirements apart from `google-cloud-dataproc` library). Just replace `dataproc_v1` for `dataproc_v1beta2` and access the endpoints with `response.config.endpoint_config`:

```py
from google.cloud import dataproc_v1beta2

project_id, cluster_name = '', ''
region = 'europe-west4'

client = dataproc_v1beta2.ClusterControllerClient(
                       client_options={
                            'api_endpoint': '{}-dataproc.googleapis.com:443'.format(region)
                        }
                    )


response = client.get_cluster(project_id, region, cluster_name)
print(response.config.endpoint_config)
```

In my case I get:

```js
http_ports {
  key: "HDFS NameNode"
  value: "https://REDACTED-dot-europe-west4.dataproc.googleusercontent.com/hdfs/dfshealth.html"
}
http_ports {
  key: "Jupyter"
  value: "https://REDACTED-dot-europe-west4.dataproc.googleusercontent.com/jupyter/"
}
http_ports {
  key: "JupyterLab"
  value: "https://REDACTED-dot-europe-west4.dataproc.googleusercontent.com/jupyter/lab/"
}
http_ports {
  key: "MapReduce Job History"
  value: "https://REDACTED-dot-europe-west4.dataproc.googleusercontent.com/jobhistory/"
}
http_ports {
  key: "Spark History Server"
  value: "https://REDACTED-dot-europe-west4.dataproc.googleusercontent.com/sparkhistory/"
}
http_ports {
  key: "Tez"
  value: "https://REDACTED-dot-europe-west4.dataproc.googleusercontent.com/apphistory/tez-ui/"
}
http_ports {
  key: "YARN Application Timeline"
  value: "https://REDACTED-dot-europe-west4.dataproc.googleusercontent.com/apphistory/"
}
http_ports {
  key: "YARN ResourceManager"
  value: "https://REDACTED-dot-europe-west4.dataproc.googleusercontent.com/yarn/"
}
enable_http_port_access: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to v1beat2

Enable the component with:

```py
'endpoint_config': {
                'enable_http_port_access': True
            },
```

then the above answer will work:

```sh
client.get_cluster(project_id, region, cluster_name)
```